# Fancybox n ot working gives no errors in Firebug, all images exist

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Fancybox is not working on this page, it has worked on lots of other sites with the same code. Firebug gives no errors.  Any idea what the problem might be?

http://www.asbestaway.ie/gallery.php

Thanks

Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your code for `$("a[rel=example_group]")` returns an empty array - meaning there is no anchor tag with the attribute `rel` whose value equals `example_group`. It looks like from your code your anchor tags have `rel="group"`, so it should work if you change it to `$("a[rel=group]")`.